# Why is my SSD estimated remaining life dropping faster than expected?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-11, storage, storage-spaces

I've used my Hynix BC501 SSD drive for about 4 years with 16.5TB total written data.

Its estimated life is now 41%, yet the expected life of my old PC's HDD, which I used for more than 10 years, is still 96%. How is it possible?

I thought SSDs had a longer lifespan than HDDs? Recommendations Please

[image: my Drive properties]

Comment: How full is the drive? SSDs can be killed early by always keeping them near capacity - this, of course, affects tiny drives [like yours 256GB or smaller] far more than large ones [1TB or larger].

Comment: Some real-world figures; Power on hours 86,219 [that's 9½ years, give or take] Total LBAs written 732,156,504,542 Current Health still registers 100%. 1TB Samsung 840 EVO installed July 2014 as boot drive in a machine that never sleeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two measurements (SSD vs. HDD) are not the same thing at all.

The SSD has fixed number of cell cycle use and provides additional cells to give a good life.  My own SSDs allow 600 TBW for lifetime. I am not half way there left.

Your drive life may be dropping faster than you expect because of use or lower surplus cell design capacity.

HDDs depend more on build design and quality and do not have a specific usage limit as do SSD's .  So as long as the HDD works and does not have errors it is fine.

I have a ThinkPad X230 from 2013 with a top notch Hitachi HDD. Ten years now, no errors and it runs as an instrumentation machine in my workshop.

Comment: To give perspective, 600 TBW lifespan is hundreds of GB (even a TB) would be between 5-10 years of constant writes. **60 TB a year would be 10 years.**

Comment: True, and overall design and quality makes a difference as well.